# Testing app beetween real device and emulator via WiFi without router

Tags: android, android-emulator, wifi

I develop app which contains a client and a server side, so I need to test work between them. I have a real android device and I want android device to connects to emulator. I'm working at work sometimes(if I have free time of course) and at home. I have the WiFi router at home and I can connect to the real device by emulator(TCP listener running on the real device), but not vise versa(I don't know which exactly IP to use). But at work I have only hot-spot WiFi point without router. My android device connects to it fine. Even more `ADB` can connect to the device when `adbWireless` running on it. But it doesn't work, I can't connect to tcp listener in any cases. The difference between home and work is existence of WiFi router. Are there any solutions? If not why `Android debug bridge(ADB)` can connect to `adbWireless`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I run tethering on my real device and run the server on it. Then I use a program `Connection state viewer` there is a link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.nolesh.android.connectionstateviewer It helps me to find IP address. After that I start the emulator and the client side on it. So I connect to my server by given IP.

Comment: Your basic problem is that the android emulator is configured not to listen on the external network interfaces of the computer running it.  To get it to accept inbound connections you would have to use a forwarding tool (not the android one) or modify the emulator.  Doing it in the other direction as you have may be more practical.  But be aware your app will probably only work on wifi, *not* on mobile networks.

Comment: I don't need to use mobile networks. I do it through WiFi and it works fine. The main problem was I didn't know IP address. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The point is that you can only connect outwards from the emulator, not inwards to it, because it only listens on the local interface of the hosting machine and not on the external interfaces.